# "Prove that any simple graph of order $n \geq 2$ has two vertices of the same degree" - is my answer sufficient?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I've seen similar answers to this but they tend to be a little more involved, am I missing something in my proof?  It goes as follows:

Given a simple graph $G = (V,E)$ of order $|V| \geq 2$, we know $|V| > \deg(v)$ for all $v \in V$.  Hence, by the pigeonhole principle there must exist $v_1, v_2 \in V$ such that $\deg(v_1) = \deg(v_2)$.  This proves the result.

I've seen some proofs through induction and by contradiction, but it seems to me that the result is proved as long as there are more vertices in the graph than there are possible degrees for each vertex, am I missing something?

Cheers !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How do you get from $|V|\gt\deg v$ to "there are more vertices than possible degrees"? Let's see. Say $|V|=4$. Four vertices, four possible degrees: $0,1,2,3$. So what? By the way, where did you use the assumption that $|V|\ge2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct! In addition, just use the fact that there can not be two vertices where one has degree $0$ and the other has degree $|V|-1$.

Comment: that makes sense!  We're working with two sets, V and the possible degrees of each node in V.  Both initially have size n, however we note that a graph cannot have both a node of 0 degree and a node of n-1 degree (because a non complete graph's vertices have a max degree of n-2), hence the size of our 2nd set is actually n-1.  Then we can apply the PHP as |V| = n > |deg(v)| = n - 1 for all v in V.  Is that all correct?

Comment: Almost but a non-complete graph may have max degree bigger than $n-2$. You only need for any graph degrees are coming from that set $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ or $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-2\}$ both of them have $n-1$ elements whereas there are $n$ vertices so two of them must have the same degree.

Comment: ahh yes I see, thank you!